# I know about what we need

Tags: word-usage, pronouns, determiners

For this sentence "I know about what we need."

I don't understand why we use "what" we need.

What is the function of  "what" ?

Is it a pronoun?

Can we use "that" instead of "what"?

Could you please explain it to me?

And could you give me some examples about using clause after preposition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's pronoun.

No, you can't use *that*, not in a word-for-word exchange, although one could say:

> "I know about **that which** we need."

That sounds a bit stilted, though, in my opinion. I think you'd be better off saying:

> "I know what we need."

(There's no need for *about* in that sentence).

Comment: How about 'I know that thing we need'?

Comment: @VijayaRagavan - I would say, "I know the thing we need..." (using _the_ instead of _that_).